# How to change the ui-view after ajax success in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Now I am trying to fire a ajax for search. after I $http( may be $resourse just ajax) success, I need to update the ui-view in index.page to show the result. Here is my code:

```
angular.module('ecom').config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
    //for any unmatched url,send to /dashboard
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard");
    $stateProvider
     .state('home',
             {
            url:'/home',
            templateUrl:'submitter/home/home.html'
             }) 
      .state('expenses',
              {
            url:'/expenses',
            templateUrl:'submitter/expenses/expense-list.html',
            controller:'SubmitterExpensesCtrl'
              })
        .state('receipts',
              {
            url:'/receipts',
            templateUrl:'submitter/receipts/receipts.html'
              })
        .state('settings',
             {
            url:'/settings',
            templateUrl:'settings/settings.html',
            controller:'SettingCtrl'
             })
        .state('logout',
              {
            url:'/logout',
            templateUrl:'logout/logout.html',
            controller:'LogoutCtrl'
              })
        .state('searchResult',
                {
            url:'/searchresult',
            templateUrl:'ExpenseResult/searchresult.html',
            controller:'resultCtrl'     
                })
}]);
This is index.page :
<nav><search></search></nav> // When click search, it will fire a ajax call, I will display the result in searchresult.html
<div class="body-container">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="container app-wrapper col-md-12" ui-view></div> //the main content will display here.
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    </div>
<footer></footer>
```

How can I change the url to /result and display the searchresult.html in  of index page?
Can I try $location.path('/searchresult') in ajax seccuee method?;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inject $state into your controller and call $state.go(statename) once the $http/$resource call has returned the promise.

So in your case, something like...

```
$http.post("/ajax")
.then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $state.go("searchResult");
})
```

Comment: Thanks! what is difference between $location.path(url) and $state.go ? seems like they do same thing, of course, $state.go is base on state name. and the $location is directly change the url. rather than this, what advantages I can take?

Comment: Theres not too much of an advantage but $state.go is just more maintainable. One of the core advantages is when providing parameters to a state. With $location.path, you have to construct a string [ie. $location.path("searchResult/" + searchid)] which I find is awfully fiddly and not very maintainable but if you use $state.go you can provide the params as an object [ie. $state.go("searchResult", {searchid:4})].